# The S3 bucket addressed by the query is in a different region from this cluster but region parameter not supported for parquet files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using the copy command to populate a Redshift database from an s3 bucket. They are in different regions, so I inserted

```
    '...FORMAT AS PARQUET REGION AS 'us-east-1'
```

but this gives the error:

```
    psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: REGION argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY
```

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: yes region argument is not suported with parquet format copy command. given in docs posted a solution to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its true region option is ot formatted for COPY from columnar data formats: `ORC and PARQUET`.

[docs says :](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-columnar.html) **The Amazon S3 bucket must be in the same AWS Region as the Amazon Redshift cluster.**

Only the following COPY parameters are supported:

```
FROM

IAM_ROLE

CREDENTIALS

STATUPDATE

MANIFEST

ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and SESSION_TOKEN.
```

**my suggestions**:- either transfer data from one s3 to another in different region. can follow this blog from aws https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/.
or launch your cluster in the region where your data is, but copy data from s3 is much feasible